# Java RMI Proxy issue

Tags: java, proxy, rmi

I am getting this error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to rmi.engine.Call
        at Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

My `Abstract` and `Call` class both extend `Remote`.

Call:

```
public class Call extends UnicastRemoteObject implements rmi.engine.Abstract {

    public Call() throws Exception {
        super(Store.PORT, new RClient(), new RServer());
    }

    public String getHello() {
        System.out.println("CONN");
        return "HEY";
    }
}
```

Abstract:

```
public interface Abstract extends Remote {

    String getHello() throws RemoteException;

}
```

This is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        try {
            System.out.println("We are slave ");
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Registry rr = LocateRegistry.
                getRegistry(ip.getHostAddress(), Store.PORT, new RClient());

            Object ss = rr.lookup("FILLER");

            System.out.println(ss.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            System.out.println(((Call)ss).getHello());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        if (args[0].equals("master")) {
            // Start Master
            try {
                RMIServer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Netbeans says the problem is on line 39 which is

```
    System.out.println(((Call)ss).getHello());
```

The output looks like this:

Run:

```
We are slave 
Connecting 10.0.0.212:5225
$Proxy0
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to rmi.engine.Call
        at Main.main(Main.java:39)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I am running a master in cmd listening on port 5225.

Comment: Really helpful to me.
As I was also creating object of server implementation instead of interface.
You should keep in mind that whenever you are calling server programs i.e. Remote methods , you should call them by interface defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `$Proxy0` is a [dynamic proxy](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html), that is, a class is generate by java at run-time.

This class should implement the interface `Abstract`, but does not extend `Call`. So you can't downcast it to `Call` (this gives a class cast), but downcasting it to `Abstract` should be ok.

If you use RMI, you should only communicate with remote object through interfaces.

*PS: `Abstract` is kind of a confusing name. I really thought that you were speaking of [abstract class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) first. I would rename that if possible. Same for `rmi.engine`, prefer something like `org.myproject`, to avoid confusion with internal class of the JDK.*

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the obvious mistake! Lifesaver!