# RMI on client side generating exception when getting a reference to the RMI server

Tags: java, rmi

When I try to run an RMI client after running the RMI server I get the following exception:

```
EncodeInterface exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy30 cannot be cast to hw2.chat.backend.main.EncodeInterface
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy30 cannot be cast to hw2.chat.backend.main.EncodeInterface
at hw2.chat.backend.main.EncodingRmiClient.initialiseRMIClient(EncodingRmiClient.java:26)
```

And the relevant code in the RMI client is:

```
EncodeInterface encodeInterface;
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, portNumber);
encodeInterface = (EncodeInterface)registry.lookup("RmiEncodingServer"); //line 26
```

And in the RMI server:

```
    try
    {
        EncodeInterface encodeInterface = new EncoderImpl();
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind("RmiEncodingServer", encodeInterface);
        System.out.println("RmiEncodingServer is running...");
    }
```

`EncodeInterface` is the interface that extends `Remote` and that is present in the client side too.

Host is "127.0.0.1" and portNumber is 1099 (I am assuming it should be the default value which is 1099 since I didn't specify it when I ran my `RmiEncodingServer`).

If I don’t run the RMI server I get the same exception, any ideas as to why this is happening?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a different package name on the server and client side, but the classes distributed to the client need to be exactly the same as in the server..

Answer (score 1):

A `ClassCastException` usually mean that either

- `EncoderImpl` does not implement `EncodeInterface`, or
- The .jar on the client-side and server-side are different, resulting in two versions of the class to be deployed, which are considered different.

Few hints:

1. Check that you implement the interface, e.g.

   `EncoderImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements EncodeInterface`
2. Add a version id to your class as supported by java [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/), e.g.

   `static final long serialVersionUID = 10275539472837495L;`
3. Clean, rebuild, and redeploy, and restart everything to make sure the same jar are deployed everywere and that there isn't a server running somewhere already

Hope it helps, otherwise provide more info in the question.

Related question: [Java RMI proxy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821759/java-rmi-proxy-issue)