# RMI client 'cannot cast to' exception

Tags: java, rmi

Let's say I have these lines:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(2121);
RemoteObject probe = (RemoteObject)registry.lookup(REMOTE_OBJ_NAME);//this throws exception
probe.doSomething();
```

The exception is this:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy1 cannot be cast to app.RemoteObject`

For the sake of clarity, the `RemoteObject` implements an interface which extends `java.rmi.Remote`.

Comment: What type does `registry.lookup` return?

Comment: Similar issue, maybe the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821759/java-rmi-proxy-issue

Comment: @Joe just a Remote that implements all intefaces from the original object that also extend Remote

Comment: @Joe It's there in the exception: `$Proxy1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast to interface that extended Remote

```
RemoteInterface probe = (RemoteInterface)registry.lookup(REMOTE_OBJ_NAME);
probe.doSomething();
```

this is because you never get the actual object back but a stub object that forwards any method calls to the actual object

Comment: someone had posted a comment with the same suggestion. Issue solved!

Answer (score -1):

do not extends Remote if your class implements Serializable

Comment: (a) why not? (b) doesn't answer the question.