# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot be cast to

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

**Server:**

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

InventoryInterface Inventory = new Inventory(registry);

registry.bind("Inventory", Inventory);
```

**Client:**

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);


InventoryInterface inventory = (InventoryInterface) registry.lookup("Inventory");


String product_id = inventory.newProduct();

ProductFacade product_1 = (ProductFacade) registry.lookup(product_id);
```

The Problem is the exception happens at the casting, in this case it happens at: `ProductFacade product_1 = (ProductFacade) registry.lookup(product_id);`

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2 cannot be cast to rmi.ProductFacade
```

Comment: Please provide the implementation of `InventoryInterface.newProduct()`.

Comment: @EJP Done, Check the new edit

Comment: The code in the new edit cannot possibly cause the problem you are asking about. It is part of the solution I proposed, not part of the code that causes the problem you're asking about.

Comment: you asked for the implementation of `InventoryInterface.newProduct()`

Comment: I asked for the implementation of `String newProduct()` as specified in your original `InventoryInterface` pre edit, and as called by your client code above,  and you have provided an implementation of `ProductFacade newProduct()`, which is what I suggested in my answer, and which cannot throw `ClassCastException` on the subsequent lookup because there is no `String` to lookup, and as you already have the new `ProductFacade` you wouldn't be doing a lookup anyway. Unclear what you're asking, and no valid code supplied that exhibits the problem being asked about.

Comment: Three hours and three edits and you still haven't provided what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is bound to the Registry under the name you're looking up does not implement the `rmi.ProductFacade` remote interface.

> So I'm wondering if i should for example restart the Registry before casting again

Certainly not. (a) You can't restart it from the client, and (b) all you would get would be an empty Registry. The suggestion doesn't make sense.

Hard to see why `InventoryInterface.newProduct()` returns a `String` instead of the actual new `ProductFacade` object. Also why `listAllProducts()` returns a `String` rather than a `String[]`. I would redesign this without such heavy use of the Registry as follows:

```
public interface InventoryInterface extends Remote {    
    public ProductFacade newProduct() throws RemoteException;
    public ProductFacade getProduct(String id) throws RemoteException;    
    public String[] listAllProducts() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: My code works for both lookups only if i tested each separately

Comment: I do not understand. There are three lookups here, not two, and you cannot lookup a product ID unless you already have one, and you get one from `inventory.newProduct()`, and you can't call that unless you've done a prior lookup on the inventory object.

Answer (score 0):

It can be about how you bind it.  For example, if ProductFacade implements InventoryInterface you might need to cast it as InventoryInterface instead of ProductFacade.

Comment: No binding is correct, i have mentioned that the first cast always works, but the second cast has the exception (In terms of order). So I'm wondering if i should for example restart the Registry before casting again or what could be the problem?

Comment: Is AdminFacade an Interface while ProductFacade not?

Comment: both are interfaces

Comment: But if I lookup at `"Inventory"` first, the exception happens at the admin casting line

Comment: In RMI, you should only communicate with remote object through interfaces.  you need to cast to interface that extended Remote. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496135/rmi-client-cannot-cast-to-exception  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821759/java-rmi-proxy-issue

Comment: Did ProductFacade extends Remote?

Comment: Yes it extends Remote, Please see the new edit for the question

Comment: Could that be a duplicate ID?  Note whether you got an `AlreadyBoundException`?  Just in case you have some number as ID like new admin has ID "1" and so does the new product.